# cannot patch class because of __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm writing unit tests for a codebase. My issue is I need to patch a database abstraction class but it is masked by the `__init__.py` file. My file structure is:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── tools
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_tool1.py
│   ├── tool1.py
│   └── tool2.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── sql_client.py
```

Now the content of the files:

```
# tools/__init__.py
from .tool1 import *  # `SQLClient` is imported here as part of tool1
from .tool2 import *  # `SQLClient` is imported here again but now it's part of tool2
```

```
# tools/tool1.py
from utils import SQLClient

class A(object):
    ...
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        # the function I want to test
        sql = SQLClient("some id")
```

```
# tools/tool2.py
from utils import SQLClient
...
```

```
# utils/__init__.py
from sql_client import *
```

```
# utils/sql_client.py
class SQLClient(object):
    # The sql abstraction class that needs to be patched
```

In my test file, I'm creating a mock class to be used as the patch. I'm using absolute imports in my tests because later I want to move all the tests outside of the source folders.

```
# tools/test/test_tool1.py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from utils import SQLClient
from tools import A

class MockSQLClient(MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(spec=SQLClient)
        self._mocks = {"select *": "rows"}
    def make_query(query)
        return self._mocks[query]

def test_run_func(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("tools.SQLClient", MockSQLClient)
    a = A()
    a.run()
    # rest of the test
```

Now, the issue is that `tools/__init__.py` imports everything from all the submodules so `SQLClient` from `tool1` is being masked by `SQLClient` from `tool2`. As a result, my monkeypatch is patching `tool2.SQLClient`. I cannot patch the `tool1` part directly by `monkeypatch.setattr("tools.tool1.SQLClient")` because of `tools/__init__.py` which throws an error complaining there is no `tool1` in `tools`.

**EDIT**

changed question title, more detail on where the test is.

Comment: what is the path of your test file? I would question this: _"I cannot patch the tool1 part directly by monkeypatch.setattr("tools.tool1.SQLClient") because of tools/__init__.py"_

Comment: your test file does not belong in the same folder as your actual code. the test file should live in its own folder at the root of the repository preferably

Comment: @gold_cy the location of the test doesn't really affect the issue here, you see I'm using absolute imports in my test file so I can place it anywhere and run `pytest <path to myfile>`.